# Extract specific data-bind from span class from HTML dynamic page with PHP

Tags: php, html

I need to extract some information from one Webpage which is the result of one interrogation, (it's the result of a tracking of one shipping, so every time the page I want to interrogate and get info from, is the result one some interrogation)

Here is one example:

```
 https://www.sda.it/wps/portal/Servizi_online/ricerca_spedizioni?locale=it&tracing.letteraVettura=3872809292532
```

Now the information that I want to get and copy from this result page is contained here:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-8">

    <span data-bind="text: descrizioneTracing"

class="delivery-status"></span>

   </div>
```

But in html view I can't see the result. I need to extract, that in this case is:
" La spedizione e' stata consegnata "

I have some idea and trying to use this way,

```
 $url = file_get_contents('https://www.sda.it/wps/portal/Servizi_online/ricerca_spedizioni?locale=it&tracing.letteraVettura='.$numldv);
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load($url);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname="delivery-status";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
```

I don't know if is the good direction really, and also how to print as string the result of $nodes,

after that I will go more specific as I just need

```
 data-bind="text: descrizioneTracing"
```

But for the moment I don't have idea how to do it.

Any suggestion or help?

Thank you.

Comment: They probably have an API to provide these information. Instead of scraping a page looking for dinamically added information try to search for their API and integrate a call to that into your logic

Comment: by googling a bit you will also find several third party plugin for the most common ecommerce platform (my guess you need it for this) that will provide you this functionality

Answer (score -1):

Try this one, But currently, your site URL returns an empty string

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('https://www.sda.it/wps/portal/Servizi_online/ricerca_spedizioni?locale=it&tracing.letteraVettura=3872809292532'); //get the html returned from the following url

$pokemon_doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

if(!empty($html)){ //if any html is actually returned

    $pokemon_doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

    $pokemon_xpath = new DOMXPath($pokemon_doc);

    //get all the h2's with an id
    $pokemon_row = $pokemon_xpath->query('span[data-bind="text: descrizioneTracing"]');
    echo json_encode($html);die;

    if($pokemon_row->length > 0){
        foreach($pokemon_row as $row){
            echo $row->nodeValue . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: it's empty because the data you want to retrieve is not there at DOM ready but is added later with Ajax. OP states that he cannot see the data in the HTML source too

Comment: I understand infact there is not result in the htl code of the string i am interesting,

Comment: Because is added later with Ajax, is it possible, anyway, to extract in some ways ? 

Thank you